# How to execute php file on unix server from a HTML webpage

Tags: php, html, ajax, unix, server

I have a webpage with a HTML button. The webpage is located in /var/www/html and is named index.php. In the same folder I have a file called "running.php". The contents of running.php is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {

        $action = $_POST['action'];

        switch($action) {

            case 'test' : test();

            break;

        }
    }


    function test(){

         exec("/usr/sapint/outgoing/ihprocess",$output);

         print_r($output);

   }
?>
```

when I run the file from command line on the server as ./running.php the file executes perfectly. I want to be able to execute this file from the HTML webpage.

I have played around with all the options such as exec, permissions etc but nothing seems to work.

I currently have in my index.php file

```
<a id="run" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ajaxcall()">Process Files </a>

   function ajaxcall() {    

    $.ajax({ url: 'running.php',
     data: {action: 'test'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
  });

}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `<a id="run" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ajaxcall()">Process Files </a>` — Why isn't this a `<button>`?

Comment: You haven't said what **does** happen. Does the HTTP request get made? Does it get a response? Are there errors? Have you turned PHP's error logging up so you can see all the errors?

Comment: I have changed it to a <button> but it still does not work.

Comment: nothing happens, there are no errors, no response at all.

Comment: No response at all **and** no error? If there's no response then the browser should report a time out error on the network tab.

Comment: Nope nothing, when i click on the button I have a javascript function which disables the button (greys it out) for 15 seconds. Other than that there is no repsponse. Any ideas?

Comment: is request is going to server, check console.

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji — How are you testing for the response? Do you know how to use the Network tab in the Developer Tools?

Comment: well to be fair you aren't actually doing anything with the response, if any is sent. Your "success" function is empty and you've no "error" function. So if there _is_ a response you're just ignoring it. You can always check your network tab in the browser to watch the request and see if it's succeeding, and what is being sent in the response. Once you're satisifed with that, you need to write some script in the "success" function to inject the response into your page (or whatever you intend to do with it). You might also want to write some code to handle errors if the request ever fails.

Comment: @ADyson I noticed that and have ammended it. On the Network tab I am getting an error "POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.x/running.php 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: A 500 error means something went wrong with the PHP script on the server. So you need to debug that script. Maybe it doesn't have permission to execute that other command, or something. Webservers usually (should) run with fairly restricted privileges.

Comment: @ADyson Check the edit above.   exec("/usr/sapint/outgoing/ihprocess",$output); for some reason does not execute. ihprocess is another php file in a seperate location on the same server.

Comment: Ok so first have you verified that the "action" $_POST variable gets set correctly? If that's not there then it will never execute. If that's ok, then rather than calling exec, you could just have an "include" statement to include the "ihprocess" PHP script and it will then execute it as if it were part of the main script. "exec" is intended for running external programs, I can't really see a reason to use it to execute another PHP script.

Comment: managed to get it working. exec worked fine. Thanks for all the help :)